# Left Join in Entity Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to left join on entity frame work 3.5 but i am unable to do so...

```
from i in
    (from ta in context.test_attempt
     join uf in context.user_flag on ta.users.USERID equals uf.UserID)
select i;
```

I want to use left join instead to join?

Comment: Entity Framework 3.5 does not exist. Do you mean EF 1, 4, 4.1 or 4.2 (probably 1)?

Comment: I assume he means EF1 for .NET 3.5. To be honest you really shouldn't be using EF1. Very flawed. Either upgrade to EF and .NET 4 or use another ORM IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `DefaultIfEmpty()` for an outer join:

```
from ta in context.test_attempt
join uf in context.user_flag on ta.users.USERID equals uf.UserID into g
from uf in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { ta, uf }
```

Your outer from/select above is unnecessary, just project `ta` and `uf` into what you need.

Comment: DefaultIfEmpty() is not supported for entity framework 3.5. I had tried this  but it gives error..........

Comment: Then I think you're out of luck. :(

Comment: Is there is any other way except DefaultIfEmpty()  as entity framework 3.5 doesnot supported this?

Answer (score 0):

You will find examples of different LINQ joins here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9 and loads of other LINQ examples too.

Comment: DefaultIfEmpty() is not supported for entity framework 1.1. I had tried this but it gives error.......... –

Answer (score 0):

> Entity framework in .NET 3.5 doesn't offer left join in Linq queries.
>   The way to get "joined records" is through navigation property between
>   entities

From here: [Left Outer Join in Entity Data Model asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5919955/2387977)