# linq multi left join to same property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, .net-3.5, left-join

Is it possible to write a LINQ for this query? (in .NET 3.5)

```
select tt.id
     ,tt.detailscount
     ,ttdmx.detailorder
     ,ttdmx.detailtype
     ,ttdm1.detailorder
     ,ttdm1.detailtype
     ,ttdm2.detailorder
     ,ttdm2.detailtype
from test.testtable tt
left join test.testtabledetails ttdmx on tt.id = ttdmx.causeid 
    and tt.maxcausedetailorder = ttdmx.detailorder
left join test.testtabledetails ttdm1 on tt.id = ttdm1.causeid 
    and tt.maxcausedetailorder - 1 = ttdm1.detailorder
left join test.testtabledetails ttdm2 on tt.id = ttdm2.causeid 
    and tt.maxcausedetailorder - 2 = ttdm2.detailorder
```

The classes are something like this:

```
public class Test {
  public int id {get;set;}
  public IList<TestDetails> details {get;set}
}
```

and

```
public class TestDetails {
  public int id {get;set;}
  public int detailOrder {get;set;}
  public int detailType {get;set;}
}
```

I tried with queryOver but it can't join to the same property twice.

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean here. Do you have an analogous in memory collection that you want to write a LINQ query against, or are you interested in writing a LINQ expression that can be translated into the SQL above by some ORM?

Comment: I want a LINQ expression that can be translated into the SQL above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to write:

```
...
from ttdmx in db.testtabledetails.Where(x => 
    tt.id == x.causeid && 
    tt.maxcausedetailorder == x.detailorder).DefaultIfEmpty()
...
```

This will be translated into a SQL left join

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use .NET 3.5, so .DefaultIfEmpty() not work. But thanks anyway. I think i will need to change the classes

Comment: I get an error that says not recognize the method DefaultIfEmpty http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415581/left-join-in-entity-framework-3-5

Comment: @intstck Seems you are right. Drop Entity framework and use Linq to SQL instead or upgrade to a newer version. Or just execute the SQL directly, you can still map the result to EF entities.